# Shorthands for setting query parameters to variables

Tags: go

Is there a shorter/neater way to write this? Where `r` is `r *http.Request`

```
var page, pageOffset, ignoreCase = "", "20", "false"
p := r.FormValue("page")
o := r.FormValue("pageOffset")
i := r.FormValue("ignoreCase")
if p != "" {
    page = p
}
if o != "" {
    pageOffset = o
}
if i != "" {
    ignoreCase = i
}
```

Trying to grab query parameter values and trying to write neater code to do so.

Comment: No, there is not. Unless you write a function.

Comment: You can combine the if statement and assignment, of course: `if p := r.FormValue("page"); p != "" {`

Comment: yo can look for a package to handle binding query params to struct.

Answer (score 5):

```
func DefaultFormQuery(r *http.Request, key string, defaultValue string) string {
  if v := r.FormValue(key); v != "" {
     return v
  }
  return defaultValue
}
```

Answer (score 3):

This is a shorter way to express your exact functionality:

```golang
var pageOffset, ignoreCase = "20", "false"
page := r.FormValue("page") // No need to check if r.FormValue("page") == "", if the default is "", just set it
if o := r.FormValue("pageOffset"); o != "" {
    pageOffset = o
}
if i := r.FormValue("ignoreCase"); i != "" {
    ignoreCase = i
}
```

Depending on what kind of error checking you want to do, and if you want to convert to more natural types, you might be able to do something like this:

```golang
page := r.FormValue("page") // Maybe this should be converted to an int, too? Not sure how it's used.
pageOffset := 20
if o, err := strconv.Atoi(r.FormValue("pageOffset")); err == nil {
    pageOffset = o
}
ignoreCase := r.FormValue("ignoreCase") == "true"
```